# Local or Private NPM module when deploying to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, procfile

I have a node app that has a local npm module `npm link ./local` and I'm trying to deploy the app to heroku. Heroku runs `npm install` when I deploy, but `npm link`'s aren't saved in `package.json` so my local module is missing.

I'm new to heroku and `Procfiles`, I'd like to run a script or just run `npm link ./local` before on the heroku box.

Alternatively I could put the module on github as a private repository and link it from there. But as far as I know Heroku isn't able to download private repo. Can I give Heroku access to my github repository via keys so that it could download it?

I'd love for somekind of solution! Anything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need yo put modules in node_modules folder and push that to heroku

Procfiles are easy to maintain and heroku will read that

I have sample Procfile like

```
web: bin/hubot -a campfire
```

Even heroku also says that best is to include node_modules into repo so you can just include your local packages into that.

See more here [Heroku Node Deploy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs)

Comment: I guess that would do the trick. Something about not git-ignoring `npm_modules` makes my brain fart.

Comment: So I don't think that git is following my `npm link` aka `symlink`. I don't think it's safe to put my actual code inside `node_modules`. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: So I got it to work, `npm link` dosn't link it relative like I thought It did so I had to `cd` into `node_module` and `ln` directly. `node_modules$ ln -s ../local_module/ ./local_module`